# AAPT: error: attribute android:killAble not found

Tags: android

i create custom attribute use by `BindingAdapter`,but it unable to use in layout

BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter("android:killAble")
fun View.setKillAble(killAble: Boolean) {
    this.isEnabled = killAble
}
```

layout

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/et_height"
    android:killAble="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_name"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    />
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
             savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding: FragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, 
        R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val rootView = binding.root
        val viewmodel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewmodel
        return rootView
    }
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 15):

You must use the data binding syntax:

```
android:killAble="@{true}"
```

Comment: Thnx. That resolved my issue today.